# Example of a module that is finitely generated, finitely cogenerated and linearly compact, but not Artinian!

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, finitely-generated, artinian

> I need an example of a module that is finitely generated, finitely cogenerated and also linearly compact (in discrete topology) but not Artinian.

In fact I proved a theorem with this strong assumptions and I am not sure that there is such a module except finitely generated Artinian modules (and my result for finitely generated Artinian modules is obvious). 
For the definition of finitely cogenerated modules one can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_module. Can anyone give me such an example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now that we have your "needs" out of the way, perhaps we can briefly look at what you've considered, and how you came about the question?

Comment: @rschwieb Ok, i proof a theorem with this assumptions: Let $M$ be an $R$-module that is finitely generated, finitely cogenerated and linearly compact! I am not sure that is there any module with this strong assumptions except finitely generated Artinian module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a Noetherian commutative local ring $R$, complete in the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology ($\mathfrak{m}$ the maximal ideal and $E$ the injective envelope of $R/\mathfrak{m}$, then the canonical embedding $R\to\operatorname{End}(E_R)$ is an isomorphism (Matlis, 1958). The trivial extension of $E$ by $R$, that is the ring $A=R\times E$ with operations
$$
(r,x)+(s,y)=(r+s,x+y),\qquad
(r,x)(s,y)=(rs,ry+xs)
$$
is then a ring with a Morita duality induced by the bimodule $_AA_A$ [(Dikranjan, Gregorio and Orsatti, 1991, Example 1.13)](http://www.numdam.org/article/RSMUP_1991__85__147_0.pdf). In particular it is finitely cogenerated and also linearly compact in the discrete topology (Müller, 1970).

Answer (score 1):

There are three examples [in this search](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=103l&L=63l) of rings which, considered as modules over themselves, have that property.

The easiest one to re-describe here is the trivial extension of the Prufer group $\mathbb Z(p^\infty)$ by $\mathbb Z$. (Its label there is "Finitely cogenerated, not semilocal ring".)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw these examples. Are these also linearly compact? Of course, i know $F[|x|]$ is linearly compact, but what about the field of fractions of this ring?

Comment: @SAliMousavi Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with linearly compact modules. I also don't know what you mean by $F[|x|]$: is that your notation for $F[[x]]$?

Comment: Excuse me. Yes. your notation is correct. $F[[x]]$